# How should one set up full-disk encryption on OpenBSD?

Tags: security, openbsd, encryption

Is there a preferred method to set up full-disk encryption under OpenBSD, similar to `dm-crypt` under Linux?

I'm looking for full-disk encryption, as if someone were to steal my notebook they could potentially access the data stored on it. Another reason is that I'm not always next to my notebook, so someone could potentially compromise the integrity of my netbook. These are the two major issues which make me believe that full-disk encryption is important for me.

Comment: You had two completely unrelated questions. Since I answered one and no one has answered the other yet, I removed the part about Chrome from your question. Feel free to post a new question about running Chrome on OpenBSD.

Comment: thank you! - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9723/google-chrome-on-openbsd

Comment: From [OpenBSD 5.3](http://www.openbsd.org/53.html), full disc encryption is available! > softraid(4) RAID1 and crypto volumes are now bootable on i386 and
> amd64 (full disk encryption). So besides the bootloader, EVERYTHING is encrpyted. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OpenBSD supports full-disk encryption only since [OpenBSD 5.3](http://www.openbsd.org/53.html). Earlier versions require a cleartext boot partition. I don't know when the installer was modified to support direct installation to an encrypted partition (with the bootloader still unencrypted of course, because something has to decrypt the next bit).

There's little use in encrypting the system partition anyway¹. So I suggest installing the system normally, then creating an encrypted filesystem image and putting your sensitive data (`/home`, parts of `/var`, perhaps a few files in `/etc`) there.

If you want to encrypt the system partition anyway (because you have some special use case, like some confidential software), and you didn't install an encrypted system originally, here's how you can do it.

Boot into your OpenBSD installation and create a file that will contain the encrypted filesystem image. Make sure to choose a reasonable size since it'll be hard to change later (you can create an additional image, but you'll have to enter the passphrase separately for each image). The [`vnconfig`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=vnconfig&sektion=8) man page has examples (though they're missing a few steps). In a nutshell:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/ENCRYPTED.img bs=1m count=4096
vnconfig -k svnd0 /ENCRYPTED.img  # type your passphrase
{ echo a a; echo w; echo q; } | disklabel -E /svnd0  # create a single slice
newfs /dev/svnd0a
mount /dev/svnd0a /mnt
mv /home/* /mnt
umount /mnt
umount /dev/svnd0c
```

Add corresponding entries to [`/etc/fstab`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=fstab&sektion=5):

```
 /ENCRYPTED.img  /dev/svnd0c  vnd rw,noauto,-k
 /dev/svnd0a     /home        ffs rw,noauto
```

Add commands to mount the encrypted volume and the filesystem in it at boot time to [`/etc/rc.local`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=rc.local&sektion=8):

```
echo "Mounting encrypted volumes:"
mount /dev/svnd0c
fsck -p /dev/svnd0a
mount /home
```

Check that everything is working correctly by running these commands (`mount /dev/svnd0c && mount /home`).

Note that `rc.local` is executed late in the boot process, so you can't put files used by the standard services such as ssh or sendmail on the encrypted volume. If you want to do that, put these commands in `/etc/rc` instead, just after `mount -a`. Then move the parts of your filesystem you consider to be sensitive and move them to the `/home` volume.

```
mkdir /home/etc /home/var
mv /etc/ssh /home/etc
ln -s ../home/etc/ssh /home/etc
mv /var/mail /var/spool /home/var
ln -s ../home/var/mail ../home/var/spool /var
```

You should encrypt your swap as well, but OpenBSD does that automatically nowadays.

The newer way to get an encrypted filesystem is [through the software raid driver](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#softraid) [`softraid`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=softraid&sektion=4). See the [`softraid`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=softraid&sektion=4) and [`bioctl`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bioctl&sektion=8) man pages or [Lykle de Vries's OpenBSD encrypted NAS HOWTO](http://www2.geektechnique.org/projectlab/797/openbsd-encrypted-nas-howto.html) for more information. Recent versions of OpenBSD support booting from a softraid volume and [installing](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#softraidDI) to a softraid volume by dropping to a shell during the installation to create the volume.

¹ 
<sub>As far as I can tell, OpenBSD's [volume encryption](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=vnconfig&sektion=8) is protected for confidentiality (with Blowfish), not for [integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIA_triad#Integrity). Protecting the OS's integrity is important, but there's no need for confidentiality. There are ways to protect the OS's integrity as well, but they are beyond the scope of this answer.</sub>

Comment: Can you clarify the statement "Protecting the OS's integrity is important, but there's no need for confidentiality"? Do you mean that OpenBSD's volume encryption is just marketing gimmick or not-that-important-thing?

Comment: More about integrity: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/how-to-quarantee-the-integrity-of-os

Comment: @hhh: OpenBSD's encryption provides confidentiality. That's important for your own data, not important for the OS files that anyone can download. (i.e. volume encrpytion is important but not the full story.) Integrity is defense against someone covertly changing your data, or worse, installing malware if they have physical access to your disk — an [evil maid attack](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/10/evil_maid_attac.html). Evil maid attacks are hard to defend against (I don't know what OpenBSD has to offer), but also hard to carry out.

Comment: This answer is no more correct, on OpenBSD 5.7 and earlier is already possible to install OS in encrypted partition since the beginning

Comment: @Freedom I've updated my answer to mention this possibility. Apparently it's been possible since 5.3, which didn't exist yet back when I wrote this answer.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong but softraid0 is designed to encrypt the entire disk. Furthermore stacking crypto and raid is not fully supported. Like you I’ve never been a big fan of encrypting entire disks. It’s too invasive, and the likelihood of a forensic expert stealing my disks is slim to none. The vnd is more flexible. people mock it because it uses blowfish, but strong passwords mitigate that issue.

Answer (score 3):

[Softraid](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=softraid&sektion=4) with the CRYPTO discipline was intended by the OBSD designers to support full-disk encryption.  There was another method as well with SVND that is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

http://geekyschmidt.com/2011/01/19/configuring-openbsd-softraid-fo-encryption is basically a graphical how-to of softraid full disc encryption. Of course never blindly follow guides and make sure all the bioctl settings are correct.