# Google Chrome on OpenBSD

Tags: chrome, openbsd

How can I install Google Chrome on OpenBSD?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chrome has been in OpenBSD's ports tree since at least OpenBSD 4.8.

```
$ doas pkg_add chromium
```

Should do the trick, assuming your [`/etc/installurl`](https://man.openbsd.org/installurl) file is correct or your `PKG_PATH` environment variable is properly set.

For more information on ports/packages, see here: [OpenBSD Packages and Ports System](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html#PkgMgmt)

Comment: Any known issues with Chrome? do you happen to know if it works with AwesomeWM?

Comment: @Justin:  No major issues while I've been using it. I don't know if it works with AwesomeWM... I use cwm, and it works fine there.

Comment: @gabe.: Does plucking tabs out of a window and back again work four you in cwm? They don't want to snap back in for me.

Comment: @Matej -- nope, doesn't work for me either!

Answer (score 0):

I am just revising the answer for OpenBSD 6.3 which uses 'doas' instead of 'sudo':

1. modify doas.conf

> permit nopass  as root

2. Execute the pkg_add for to install chromium

> doas pkg_add -v chromium

Comment: Your `doas.conf` has a syntax error (it lacks the identity to permit switching to root as). A sufficient `doas.ronf` may have the line `permit persist setenv { -ENV PS1=$DOAS_PS1 SSH_AUTH_SOCK } :wheel` (allows all `wheel` group users to switch to root). Not requiring passwords at all is a bit lazy, IMHO.